# Xamarin in Visual Studio and accessing webservice on local machine using 10.0.2.2

Tags: c#, android, web-services, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2013 and trying to access a webservice running on the same (local) machine.

I'm using 10.0.2.2:2414 in the emulator, but the connection is refused.  I can use the browser in the emulator (using 10.0.2.2:2414) to display the webservice methods, but still the connection is refused when trying to access a simple method that returns the string "Connected".

I've disabled the firewall on the local machine, still cannot connect.  I've tried using the IP address of the localhost (192.168.10.9), still the connection is refused.

Yes, I do have access INTERNET in the manifest. I'm running on Windows 7 Pro.  Very frustrating.  I'm at a loss as what to try next.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the loopback IP address instead: 127.0.0.1

Comment: The loopback address on the emulator refers to the emulater, not the localhost.  Doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, okay. In this case I think you are essentially working with two different networks. Somehow you will need to determine the address (beginning with 10.0...) of your local machine from the emulator. Have you tried 10.0.2.1?

Comment: 10.0.2.1 is the emulator's gateway address, see http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html.  The link explains it all, the part that has me frustrated is that I can browse to the webservice using the browser on the emulator, yet I cannot access any of the methods with a call to the webservice in the code.  I get the connection refused regardless of what IP address I use, and just for giggles I tried 127.0.0.1, as expected, same error.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it makes more sense to me now. Unfortunately, now I'm at the same level of 'stumped' as you are!

Comment: Funny thing is, I could access the production version of the webservice just fine until I had to disable TLS v1.0 on the server, Xamarin doesn't support anything other than TLS v1.0, so I'm screwed there.  The other thing is I'm on travel and I'm trying this over a VPN link, figured all I needed to do was run the webservice in the IDE and I'd be able to resume development while I figure out ModernHttpClient which apparently supports TLSv1.2 and TLS v1.1.  But, no such luck.  I'm going to have to wait until I return to the office and set this up on a test webserver.